# Element not interactable Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(6, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
JavascriptExecutor j = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
j.executeScript ("document.getElementById('spree_user_email').value='xyz';");
String s = (String) j.executeScript("return document.getElementById('spree_user_email').value");
```

i'm trying to signup for the URL   https://www.urbanladder.com/

and it's showing error element not interactable as the element is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below to enter the email and password

```
WebElement  email = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='signup_form']//input[@id='spree_user_email']"))

email.sendKeys("someeEmail@email.com")

WebElement pass = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@placeholder='Password*'])[2]"))

pass.sendKeys("Password")
```

Also, please provide more detail if this does not solve your issue.